# Cannot edit group-owned files as user belonging to that group

Tags: permissions, apache2, user-management, www

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server on Digital Ocean. I'm trying to make it so I can edit files in `/srv/www` from my normal user account, without needing to be root.

Currently, `/srv/www` is owned by `www-data:www-data`:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www
```

I've also set the permissions on all files to `664`, and on directories to `755`:

```
sudo find /srv/www/ -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /srv/www/ -type d -exec sudo chmod 755 {} \;
```

And I added my user, `shea`, to the `www-data` group:

```
sudo adduser shea www-data
```

However, when I try to `touch /srv/www/foo`, I receive the following error:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/srv/www/foo’: Permission denied
```

It works fine if I prepend `sudo` to that command, but I'd rather not do that all the time; plus it doesn't work over SFTP.

Changing the owner to `shea:www-data` allows me to write to the files, but then WordPress cannot update plugins and themes.

```
sudo chown -R shea:www-data /srv/www
```

Is there anyway that `www-data` and `shea` users can both have access to `/srv/www`? I was under the impression that adding both users to a group would do the trick, but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're setting 644 which is group read, not write!

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www
sudo chmod -R g+w /srv/www
```

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem running 16.04 on DigitalOcean. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Give write access to the group associated with a file under `/var/www/html`

   ```
   sudo find /srv/www/ -type f -exec sudo chmod 664 {} \;
   ```
2. Add `myuser` to the `www-data` group:

   ```
   sudo adduser myuser www-data
   ```
3. Confirm permissions, e.g.:

   ```
   ls -la /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/responsive/style.css
   ```

   gives

   ```
   -rw-rw-r-- www-data www-data 3892 Jan  1 2017 style.css
   ```
4. Confirm group membership: `id myuser` gives

   ```
   uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),33(www-data),110*lxd)
   ```

However, when I then tried to update `style.css` without `sudo` with my `myuser` account, I got a `permission denied` error.

#### Solution

I had to log out and log back in again from all sessions that were logged in as `myuser` before the new permissions began to take effect. Not sure why, but hope this may help anyone else in a similar situation.

Comment: logging out and logging back in worked for me. thanks so much.

Comment: logging out and logging back in worked for me. thanks so much.

Comment: Can't believe that was the problem for me as well. smh

Comment: Note that with Bitvise, you might need to fully log out from the connection, not just the terminal window